# How to get Bearer token from a request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am expecting a JWT token from all the incoming request, and it should be included on request headers like: `Authorization => 'Bearer: some token here'`

I want to get this token and verify it: here is what I am trying:

```
$token = $request->header('Authorization');
```

and this is what I get:

```
"Authorization: Bearer: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJleGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6ImV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxMzU2OTk5NTI0LCJuYmYiOjEzNTcwMDAwMDB9.UQUJV7KmNWPiwiVFAqr4Kx6O6yd69lfbtyWF8qa8iMN2dpZZ1t6xaF8HUmY46y9pZN76f5UMGA0p_CMqymRdYfNiKsiTd2V_3Qpt9LObaLg6rq18j3GLHfdr8nyBzO3v7gTpmNaU6Xy47aMDsbcs593Lx_lD3PnO41oEHgih7CsRKW1WcW1radnpEhdDO7-GpmGOF6xUnpAlQ9EHqpqnIlZPbVoJg92Iwozn-07uuWrkyKUpYN4IPpstd1ks3cKlJ6FH-2ROiC4N0MVLxp4lhUyKhLdwgDWYH4tjtdrEVK0a3_zVtK1ukvriEJqMkfYHnE6Bwv_pv_-lRNy_y7m-YQ"
```

Question is there any way to grab only the token not including `"Authorization: Bearer"`
  and of course I could parse the whole string and get the token, but I am just wondering if there is another way of getting it without parsing.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth for this?

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a built-in method to get this for you, but there's many packages you can use if you don't want to parse the string yourself (of course if you use a package it's not because you don't want to parse a string but because it also has other functionality which you need).

Comment: @MatthewDaly no I am not using that package since I cant make it work with rs256 encryption for some reasons. I am using firebase to sign and veryfy tokens using public/private keys

Answer (score 88):

There is a `bearerToken()` method on the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object, so you should be able to just do `$token = $request->bearerToken();` and get back what you expect (that's in Laravel 5.5 - I'm not sure of previous versions).

Comment: that would be awesome if it really exists

Comment: It does exist. [Request Bearer Token](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_bearerToken)

Comment: I too verified, bearerToken() method is available from Laravel version 5.2

Comment: Did anybody care how to **set** the bearer token within your PHPUnit tests? For those interested when within the PHUnit test menthod add the following: `$actual = $this->call('GET', '/the-api-uri', [], [], [], ['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);` See more explanations [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/laravel-testig-request-setting-header) in MarkRedeman's answer.

Comment: As of Laravel 8, the method exists, and it works

Comment: I confirm. As of Lumen 8, it exists. I am sure it would exist in Laravel too as @kamasuPaul has confirmed.

Comment: Wow, it worked like a charm, thank you so much for saving so much of my time.

Comment: Still working on Laravel v10.x

Answer (score 20):

To Get the Bearer token from Header in API call, I used below method.
It is working for me in Laravel 6.6.0

```
$token= request()->bearerToken();
```

Hope this will work for you.

> Used in Laravel 6.6.0

Note: If BearerToken not showing, Then please Cross Check if the bearerToken is available in header or not..

```
$header = $this->header('Authorization', '');        
if (Str::startsWith($header, 'Bearer ')) 
{            
     return Str::substr($header, 7);        
}
```

Comment: Please check you have added `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` 
Its working fine in Laravel 6.6.0 @QumberRizvi

Comment: For me this is working locally but not in production, no idea why, the `$request->bearerToken()` is null, the whole `Authorization` header actually. Any ideas?

Comment: Please Check ```use Illuminate\Http\Request``` is using or not & the laravel version. If any Issue please Send your Code. @Marcos

Comment: I get empty bearer even though I see it in the request...

Comment: You can crosscheck by using also 
```$header = $this->header('Authorization', '');
       if (Str::startsWith($header, 'Bearer ')) {
           return Str::substr($header, 7);
       }
```

If the Header response contain the Authorization data or not.

Answer (score 2):

The method `bearerToken()` was introduced Laravel 5.2. You can use: 
`$token = $request->bearerToken();` to get the token. In case you're planning to get token from a header with a changed text from "Bearer" to something else, you can define your own function like below:

```
  public function bearerToken()
  {
       $header = $this->header('Authorization', '');
       if (Str::startsWith($header, 'Bearer ')) {
           return Str::substr($header, 7);
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like:

```
$response = explode(':', $request->header('Authorization'));
$token = trim($response[2]);
```

Comment: `trim(explode(':', $header)[1])`

Answer (score 1):

if you use auth:api don't need set guard name 'api'

```
\Auth::guard('api')->getTokenForRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($apiKey = getallheaders()['Authorization'] ?? null) {
    $apiKey = str_replace(["Bearer", "bearer", " "], "", $apiKey);
}
```