# How to get authorization header in laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get my bearer token in laravel request

But I tried with `apache_request_headers()` I can get token . I want to do by laravel method so can you help me please ?

When I print like this ...

```
dd(apache_request_headers(), $request->header('Authorization'));
```

It show ...

```
array:11 [
  "Authorization" => "Bearer eyJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  "User-Agent" => "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0"
  "Accept" => "*/*"
  "Cache-Control" => "no-cache"
  "Postman-Token" => "xxxxx"
  "Host" => "localhost"
  "cookie" => "laravel_session=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  "accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate"
  "content-length" => "0"
  "Connection" => "keep-alive"
  "X-Prerender-Token" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
]
null
```

Comment: Are you calling that in a controller or in a middleware? Can you share your code?

Comment: If you do outside a controller or middleware, you can use the `request()` helper: `request()-> bearerToken()`

Comment: inside a controller and my laravel version 5.0 very old one

Comment: Print your `$request->headers->all()`. What you have?

Comment: It is outputting like above my question except `Authorization`

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791450/8703393

Comment: @hs-dev2MR did you try [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47158522/6656706) ?

Comment: yes bearerToken is not available in 5.0 ! It is after 5.2 version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authorization header missing in PHP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475885/authorization-header-missing-in-php-post-request)